# Not getting file data in Extjs Ajax request

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a form on form-window, and inside form window I have a form with many fields and one upload button. When try to submit form using Ajax.request I have got textfield value but can not get file data. Except filename.

```
    var fd = Ext.getCmp('users-form').form;
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('company_logo');
    console.log(fd.getEl().dom.files);
    params = {
        name            : fd.findField('name').getValue(),
        login           : fd.findField('login').getValue(),
        email           : fd.findField('email').getValue(),
        password        : fd.findField('password').getValue(),
        password_repeat : fd.findField('password_repeat').getValue(),
        id              : fd.findField('id').getValue()
        company_logo    : fd.findField('logo').getValue()
    }
    console.log(params);
Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: Scada.reqUrl('users', 'save'),
      method: 'post',
      params: {
        data: Ext.encode(params)
      },
      success: function() {
        console.log('in success');
      },
      failure: function() {
        console.log('in failure');
      }
    });
```

Here logo is input type file. I want to send logo data with ajax request. Please help me to figure out the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you started a new question instead of editing [Encode form data while fileupload true in Extjs Form Submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58688863) as this seems to be the same problem.

Assuming `logo` is your file upload field you are trying to get the file data using `getValue` does not actually return the file content (if you use modern there is a getFiles method which returns the selected file objects).

**General problems with your approach:**
As I stated in my original answer it is not a good idea to send files in a standard ajax request. In your case those problems are:

- If you expect `getValue` to return file contents, you are potentially encoding binary data into a JSON string. This will maybe work but create a large overhead and as the only available JSON datatype that could handle this content is `string` your parser would have to guess that property `company_logo` contains binary data and needs to be somehow converted into some sort of file reference.
- You are sending files without metadata, so when just adding the raw content into your JSON string you would not be able to detect the expected file type without testing the file in multiple ways
- As far as I know you would not be able to access the file content in classic toolkit at all

**Submitting the data as a form:** In your original question you explained that you submit the form instead of doing Ajax requests which is generally the preferred way.
When you submit a form that contains a file upload field the form will automatically be submitted as `multipart/form-data` the raw files are added to the request body with it's original content while preserving metadata collected by the browser.

If you look at https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.Ajax.html#method-request you would have to set `isUpload` to true and use the `form` proeprty instead of `params`, passing a reference to the parent form.